# creating a library class in c#

Tags: c#, dll

I am fairly new to this and i wanted some help in converting a method into a library class to be used as a dll. I am issue is how do i deal with textbox values that i am using to get data passed in from user.

This is my method that i am using and would like to have as a usable library class:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook { get; set; }
    void ExcelToPdf(string convertFilePath)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelWorkbook = appWord.Workbooks.Open(DocumentUNCPath.Text);

        excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, convertFilePath);
        excelWorkbook.Close();
        appWord.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you move it to a library you're going to want to inject those values into the method:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook { get; set; }

void ExcelToPdf(string convertFilePath, string documentUncPath)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excelWorkbook = appWord.Workbooks.Open(documentUncPath); // WAS DocumentUNCPath.Text

    excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, convertFilePath);
    excelWorkbook.Close();
    appWord.Quit();
}
```

and so when you call the method you'll pass in the value of `DocumentUNCPath.Text` from the form.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. So what if i have like error messages "invalid entered number please re enter" kind of message - do i also include them in the library class or not?

Comment: Yes you can put that kind of messages in your library. So that you library funcation can give user friendly exception message if passes values are wrong..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly.

In Visual Studio select, File - New - Project - Class Library.
Copy and paste your code into the class, should look something like this:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook { get; set; }
        void ExcelToPdf(string convertFilePath)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelWorkbook = appWord.Workbooks.Open(DocumentUNCPath.Text);

            excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, convertFilePath);
            excelWorkbook.Close();
            appWord.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Build the application and you will find your dll in the output bin folder.

Comment: i don't think i should have the DocumentUNCPath.Text in there because using the dll in a different program might have a different name for the textbox. but thanks for clarifying the idea.